# document link that opens outlook

Tags: document, hyperlink

I have an oft doc linked in SharePoint. What I want it to do is open this oft doc in outlook. What its doing is prompting to save it in the download file. Is there anyway I can prompt outlook to open when they click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to open it in Outlook. They have to download the file first and then follow the steps in the provided link based on what version of Outlook they are using. Sorry to bust your bubble.

[How to Open the OFT File Type](http://www.ehow.com/how_8476403_open-oft-file-type.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a MIME type to IIS to allow this file type to open in its respective client application.

Here is a quick summary I found:
https://kerseub.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/add-new-file-type-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link and it shows the download right click and say always open this kind of file then click to open. After that everytime someone clicks the link it will just open up.